# Static noise in microphone recording when laptop connected to power cable

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, microphone, jack

So, whenever I try to record my microphone, and my laptop is plugged to the power socket, I get static noise, but when I disconnect the laptop from the power socket, the noise is gone.
I know I can fix this by unplugging the laptop from the socket, but is there a thing I could buy, or something I could do to make the noise go away while still being plugged into the power socket?

Comment: I am pretty sure that's *ground noise*, could be another type of electrical interference. I don't know the solution right off, but maybe that could help your search. Is there a grounding (third) prong on the adapter plug itself?

Comment: No, I am from Europe so our adapters have only 2 prongs, but they have the two things on the sides....